# Swagger 3.0 - cannot add parameters to query parameter

Tags: express, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-3.0, swagger-jsdocs

I have node express application and am using `swagger-jsdoc & swagger-ui-express`

Inside router I place this code:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /get:
 *  get:
 *      tags: [ /api/roba/get ]
 *      summary: Vraca informacije o robi po datom id-u
 *      description: Vraca informacije o robi po datom id-u
 *      parameters:
 *          - name: robaid
 *      responses:
 *          400:
 *              description: Nije prosledjen parametar robaid
 */
```

And it does work normally, however when I try adding `description` or anything else under `- name` it doesn't display that endpoint.

I get error

> YAMLSemanticError: Implicit map keys need to be on a single line at line 7, column 18: - name: robaid

Code that does not work (I tried only with required or description thinking one of these do not work but not working):

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /get:
 *  get:
 *      tags: [ /api/roba/get ]
 *      summary: Vraca informacije o robi po datom id-u
 *      description: Vraca informacije o robi po datom id-u
 *      parameters:
 *          - name: robaid
 *          required: true
 *          description: Some description
 *      responses:
 *          400:
 *              description: Nije prosledjen parametar robaid
 */
```

Comment: You have indent issue, I guess

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VXFM2HGa Please try this

Comment: @DreamBold Yea it works.... I see what you have done... That two additional spaces solved the problem.

Comment: Perfect, let me add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the issue as the indentation isn't correct on lines of `required` and `description`, you can try the code below:

```
/**
 * @swagger
 * /get:
 *  get:
 *      tags: [ /api/roba/get ]
 *      summary: Vraca informacije o robi po datom id-u
 *      description: Vraca informacije o robi po datom id-u
 *      parameters:
 *          - name: robaid
 *            required: true
 *            description: Some description
 *      responses:
 *          400:
 *              description: Nije prosledjen parametar robaid
 */
```

Hope it helps!